# Find strings with equal content in list avoiding strings where searching value is a merged part of other word

Tags: c#, string, list, linq, contains

how to search  `string str = "three";` in list `List = new List<string> { "line one", "line two", "line three", "line four", "row three", "linethree", "three" };` to get this result:

```
line three 
row three 
three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each string with space and check if any splited string *equals* to your target string. Here is the code:

```
var list = new List<string> { "line one", "line two", "line three", "line four", "row three", "linethree", "three" };

var result = list.Where(i => i.Split(' ').Any(j => j.Equals("three"))).ToList();

//result:
//    line three 
//    row three 
//    three
```

Also you may want to use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` as the second parameter of the `Equals` method in the case that you are looking for case-insensitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

add space at the first of three like this:

```
string str = " three"
```

so it just get words

and for updated input use like this

```
string str = " "+"three"
```

Comment: hi, yes but I'm not sure if can use it this way with updated list and inputs

Comment: @LadO it work before any word have space so in just get words try it it work

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes this way it can be done, but for my particular case answer of Hossein Narimani Rad is more suitable

Answer (score 0):

Convert `str` to regex pattern by adding \b at beginning and end to find words then use `Regex.Match` to select the matches.